# How to set ts3Get key field dynamically in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have extracted file name from tSQSInput using a tExtractJSONFields component and logged it on to the console using tLogRow. How can I pass this value to the "key" field in tS3Get component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a context variable or a globalVariable

```
tSQSInput-->tExtractJsonFields-->TjavaRow
```

in tJavarow , set :

```
context.myKey=input_row.inputkey;
```

or

```
global.put("mykey",input_row.inputkey);
```

("inputkey" being the fieldname for your key)

Then in tS3Get (which you can link through a `onSubJobOK`), you can use the variable in the right field
`context.myKey` or `((String)globalMap.get("mykey"))`

If you use context variable make sure you declared it on the 'context' tab of your job.

Comment: I used the context variable the way you have explained and it worked well. Thanks.